# Hiding gwt bootstrap widgets on ipad

Tags: gwt, responsive-design, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap

i have gwt boot strap column with size 1 and this column has navtabs containing several navlinks like `<b:Column size="1" ui:field="stackedTabColumn">
                 <b:NavTabs stacked="true" ui:field="stackedTabs">
                    <b:NavLink ui:field="projectsLink">Projects </b:NavLink>`

I want to hide this stacked tab column in phone and ipad.
I tried with `stackedTabColumn.setShowOn(Device.Desktop);` but it doesnt seem to hide the column in ipad but hides on phone any way of hiding gwt bootstrap widgets om ipad.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the attribute `styleName="visible-desktop"` in your tag.

see [doc here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Comment: i tried with that it works fine for a tablet but not for ipad

Comment: **1st hypothesis :** your safari adapt the resolution of your page, and the resolution is wrong. If you add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">`, this will work.
**2nd hypothesis :** it's because you use a "new iPad" with retina screen. The resolution is  2048px * 1536px. That why bootstrap think it's a desktop screen. Hope this will help you !